# Can i add custom labels in gcloud scheduler jobs via python sdk (google-cloud-scheduler )

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filter, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

Can i add custom labels in gcloud scheduler jobs via python sdk (google-cloud-scheduler )

I want to filter jobs via list api.

List api gives option to filter via labels but not sure how can we add custom labels from python sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add labels to Cloud Scheduler jobs. Check this [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support).

You might however add labels to the resources that are called by Cloud Scheduler, such as to your Cloud Functions.